# Regex to delete a line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, multiline

I have the following pattern :

```
"gear_size"=>"small",
"gear_size"=>"medium",
"name"=>"node.cip4pc.cisco.com",
"region_name"=>"CCS",
"gear_size"=>"large",
node.cip4pc.cisco.com:10.203.24.175,
```

I need to delete the line `"gear_size"=>"small"`, and `"gear_size"=>"large"`,. 
These two lines don't have "name"=> pattern getting followed. 
So, basically I need to delete the line "gear_size" which is not followed by "name". 
I checked if the command pcregrep works, but this command is not supported.

 Any help for getting this resolved would be great. 
 Thanks.

Comment: If there is a gap, do you want the gear printed? If you have `gear_size`, `something_else`, `name`, should you print that `gear_size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** a much better solution if you need the name to come directly after

```
sed '/^"gear_size"/{N;/\n"name"=>/!D}'
```

If line matches `/^"gear_size"/`, and next line doesn't match `/^"name"=>/`, delete it.

**Original:** A horrible solution for a separation between `gear_size` and `name`

```
sed '/gear_size/{h;d};/name/{x;/^$/!{p;s/.*//};x}' file
```

Output:

```
"gear_size"=>"medium",
"name"=>"node.cip4pc.cisco.com",
"region_name"=>"CCS",
node.cip4pc.cisco.com:10.203.24.175,
```

Explanation:

Replace hold space with any line matching `/gear_size/` and delete that line (moves to the next line without printing).

If line matches `/name/`, swap the line with the hold space. If the hold space was not empty, print what it contained and empty it. Swap back.

Then, the contents of pattern space are printed by default.

Comment: Thank you so much Qualia the solution "sed '/^"gear_size"/{N;/\n"name"=>/!D}'" worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'p && /name/{print p} {p=""} /gear_size/{p=$0; next} 1' file
"gear_size"=>"medium",
"name"=>"node.cip4pc.cisco.com",
"region_name"=>"CCS",
node.cip4pc.cisco.com:10.203.24.175,
```